# Reshaping columns into rows

Tags: python, geopandas

I am new to programming and I am working with Geopandas on a dataset.

This is my data

```
[NAME                     noiseclass
Birmingham District (B)  50.0-54.9     9882
Leeds District (B)       50.0-54.9     7924
Buckinghamshire          50.0-54.9     6623
Birmingham District (B)  55.0-59.9     6372
Kirklees District (B)    50.0-54.9     5542
                                       ... 
Harrow London Boro       >=70.0           1
High Peak District (B)   >=70.0           1
Fenland District         >=70.0           1
Hartlepool (B)           >=70.0           1
Maldon District (B)      >=70.0           1
Length: 1540, dtype: int64][1]
```

I wanted to put the noiseclass and values in rows instead of columns in alignment with its district, how may I go about this?

Expected result:

```
    [NAME                     50.0-54.9  ...
    Birmingham District (B)     9882
    Leeds District (B)          7924
    Buckinghamshire             6623
...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to transpose your dataframe. Numpy has a great [transpose function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) for this that works with geopandas dataframes.

Since a geopandas dataframe is just a pandas dataframe that has a column with geometry, my example uses a regular pandas dataframe for simplicity.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": ["red","green","blue"]})
df
```

```
    A   B
0   1   red
1   2   green
2   3   blue
```

```
np.transpose(df)
```

```
    0   1   2
A   1   2   3
B   red green   blue
```